# Decomposing circular diffraction patterns

Tags: optics, diffraction, spectroscopy, data-analysis, interferometry

I have the following diffraction pattern produced by a fabry-perot etalon
[image]

The red represents the center of that pattern. Taking the mean intensity of the pattern as a function of the radius from the red dot and applying a cut-off radius results in
[image]

This clearly shows a superposition of at least two diffraction patterns. Is there any way to automatically decompose the patterns? I originally tried Fourier analysis but that resulted in a complete mess as the peaks appear to be Gaussian, not sine functions. I can fit Gaussian to all the individual peaks. But then my question is if there is an algorithm or method that would allow me to determine which gaussian belongs to which diffraction pattern. I have quite a few more diffraction patterns some of which are more complicated and I wanted to see if there is a way to automate this?

Comment: Off the top of my head (and without necessarily knowing any better), you should take the Fourier transform of the *entire* image, not just slices of it.  There could be something about the integration measure in polar coordinates that messes up the Fourier transform (like, a Bessel-function showing up).

Comment: Indeed, in 2D, the Fourier transform is something like $$\tilde{f}(k) = \int_0^rr\,dr\int_0^{2\pi}d\varphi\,\frac{e^{-i kr \cos\varphi}}{2\pi}f(r,\varphi)\,,$$ which for rotationally symmetric $f(r,\varphi)=f(r)$ takes the form $$\int_0^rdr\,rf(r)J_0(kr)\,.$$ This might or might not be the problem, but it's a place to start.

Comment: That said, I don't know of ways to numerically distinguish the two types of peaks (narrow and broad) in your diagram.  It's likely especially made difficult by the fact that it's not clear where the "zero" is.

Comment: @march thank you very much. Is there an equivalent algorithm to the fast Fourier transform for this version? Or do I do simple manual integration?

Comment: Did you try [independent component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis)? Btw, if you're more interested in a general algorithm and not the physical cause, perhaps you should rather consider the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: For computing that integral, look up "fast Hankel transform". I found [this Mathematica stack exchange page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26233/computation-of-hankel-transform-using-fft-fourier) as one of the hits, but generally speaking, I don't know if "FHT"'s are implemented standard in computing packages.  There's maybe a python script out there maybe?